# the output of for loop is not what I expect

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

My code for finding the index of an element :

```
    int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    int LowerBound =0;
    int UpperBound = a.length-1;

    int s = 10;
    int i = 0 ;
    for(i=0 ; i <=UpperBound;i++ )
    {
        System.out.print("["+i+"] "+a[i]);
        if(s==a[i])
        {
            break;
        }

    }
    
    if(i>UpperBound)
    {
        System.out.println("Value Doesn't Exist");
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

The out Put:

```
[0] 1[1] 2[2] 3[3] 4[4] 5[5] 6[6] 7[7] 8
Value Doesn't Exist
8
```

I can't understand how i variable became 8 although its value in the loop is 7.

Comment: When `i` becomes `8` the loop terminates. The `8` you print is the value of `a[7]`.

Comment: That's how ```for``` loop works . After checking the index of '7' , ```for``` loop again gets executed . It will first iterate ```i``` . So now ```i``` becomes 8 . then it will move to check the condition. The condition in the for loop fails . So the loop breaks , but the value of ```i``` will reamin as 8

Answer (score 1):

A loop exits when the condition of the loop becomes false, the condition of your loop is `i<=7`, which becomes false at `i=8`; thus, you get the value `i=8` at the end.